# Azure Active Directory sign in with Microsoft Account

Tags: c#, authorization, azure-active-directory

I'm using this sample https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-headless

Many of the samples, this one inclusive, say:

> This sample will not work with a Microsoft account, so if you signed in to the Azure portal with a Microsoft account and have never created a user account in your directory before, you need to do that now.

When I log in with my Microsoft account, the exception I get is:

```
AADSTS50020: User account '{mymicrosoftaccount}@{domain.com}'
from identity provider 'https://sts.windows.net/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/'
does not exist in tenant '{my-tenant}' and cannot access the application
'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' in that tenant.
The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. 
Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.
```

What would I need to do to allow logging in with my Microsoft account? At the moment, my authority is `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{mytenant}` Would I have to provide the user with an option to log in with a Microsoft Account, or the Active Directory account. If so, what authority do I use to allow logins with Microsoft Accounts?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try making your app a multi tenant app and then login using your Microsoft credentials to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common

See if this link is helpful. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-add-domain/

Answer (score -1):

The authority is fine.In order to enable login for a user with Microsoft account you need to select "User in another Microsoft Azure AD directory" in the add user window in the tenant on https://manage.windowsazure.com.

Comment: No clue. With the classic Azure Portal, you can indeed add a microsoft account. I don't know how to do this with the new portal. Thank you